# How to DDL results from SQL Developer Database Diff tool

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have run my Database Diff tool to compare two Oracle schemas in SQL Developer.  I have my results, and want to save these.  I know how to generate a script for the recommended changes, but how do I save the DDL output showing the differences between each of the objects?    Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*how do I save the DDL output showing the differences between each of the objects?*

We don't have a report for that. You can only save the DDL change scripts today.

Comment: That's a shame.Thanks Jeff.

Comment: It's not a simple report to produce, but that's not a very good reason for not having done so already. It's on the list of things to do, so stay tuned.